# Problem with ValidationMessageFor

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, validation

**Hi,**

I have placed the following code on my page :

```
<%: Html.ValidationSummary("Form not correct", new { @class = "errList" })%>
```

Then on each property I have somthing like :

```
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModelViewAd.Title, "*", new { @class = "val" })%>
```

The problem is that as soon as I open the page each ValidationMessageFor will show * and the ValidationSummary will show "Form not correct" even when the form has not yet been validated? The Summary list will however be shown first when the form has been validated.

I need both the ValidationMessageFor and the ValidationSummary to be shown only when the form has ben validated.

What am I missing?

Edit1: The Properties do have DataAnnotations.

Edit2:

This is how the first part of the view looks like

```
<div id="adRegistrationForm">
            <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
            <h1>Registrera din annons</h1>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModelViewAd, "*", new { @class = "val" })%>
            <br />
            <% using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Ad", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
               {%>
                <%: Html.ValidationSummary("Formuläret är inte korrekt ifyllt", new { @class = "errList" })%>

                <div class="controlTitle">
                    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelViewAd.Title)%>
                    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModelViewAd.Title, "*", new { @class = "val" })%>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ModelViewAd.Title, new { @class = "tb1" })%>
                </div><br />

                <div class="controlTitle">
                    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelViewAd.TypeOfAd)%>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <%: MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.RadioButtonListFor(model => model.ModelViewAd.TypeOfAd)) %>
                </div><br />

                <div id="divEndDate">
                    <div class="controlTitle">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelViewAd.EndDate)%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModelViewAd.EndDate, "*", new { @class = "val" })%>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ModelViewAd.EndDate)%>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And this is how the first part of the viewClass looks like :

```
[PropertiesMustMatchAttribute("P1", "P2", ErrorMessage = "Lösenorden stämmer inte")]
    public class ModelViewAdRegister
    {
        #region Fields
        private string _title;
        private string _description;
        #endregion

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Titel saknas")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Titeln får vara mellan 5-50 tecken lång")]
        [DisplayName("Titel")]
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value ?? string.Empty; }
        }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pris saknas")]
        [DisplayName("Pris (skr)")]
        public Decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Annons text saknas")]
        [DisplayName("Annons text")]
        [StringLength(50000, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Annons texten får vara mellan 10-50000 tecken lång")]
        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set { _description = value ?? string.Empty; }
        }
```

Comment: Show your controller code please?

Comment: What does your view look like?

Comment: Part of the ViewClass and the ViewPage is posted, do you really need a part of the action code to? Its alot of code that do have vary little with validation to do.

Comment: If you remove the PropertiesMustMatchAttribute from the ModelViewAdRegister then do you still have the problem? I only ask because I have read about a fair few issues with this attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that tonight and return with the result.

Comment: I have now tried to remove the PropertiesMustMatchAttribute from the ViewAdRegister but that do not solve the problem? I thought that If I have Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>mode.somthing, "*") that star will be shown only when there is a validation exception? And if there is then the ValidationSummary will also be shown where the validation text can be seen? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced your issue.
Your problem is that your validation summary is inside your form. Move this line

```
<%: Html.ValidationSummary("Formuläret är inte korrekt ifyllt", new { @class = "errList" })%>
```

To before this line :

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Ad", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
           {%>
```

And everything should work just fine !!